# socket recv hangs forever or timeout

Tags: python, sockets, recv, rpyc

I'm using [rpyc](https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to communicate between server and client. Everything was worked fine until today. My client pc can't receive message from server. So I run socket server:

```
$ python bin/rpyc_classic.py
INFO:SLAVE/18812:server started on [0.0.0.0]:18812
```

Connect like in docs:

```
import rpyc
conn = rpyc.classic.connect("10.99.100.200")
```

I tried to debug with wireshark, firewall is off and all is worked before. I'm using OSX. When I do reverse, connection working fine

[image]

Comment: Have you read this? https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tut1.html

Comment: @hek2mgl yes, of course. I did example from tutorial and it worked before. Today i ran the same code and it hangs. when receiving package from server to client 18812 -> 50490

Comment: @hek2mgl yes, you are right. My example with sending message is not correct. I updated question. When I do reverse, connection working fine